# AbstractListDetailFragment And TalkBack

Tags: android, kotlin, accessibility, talkback

In an Android app, I'm using `AbstractListDetailFragment` in a few places to handle list/details.  On a phone, it puts the details over the list, on a tablet, it puts them side by side.   Testing with TalkBack, on a phone, when I'm in the details, after I cycle through the controls on the details, it goes through the controls from the parent list highlighting areas wheere the controls on the list, but of course, the list isn't visible.  This seems really bad.

There is a more general problem.  You can reproduce this problem with fragments and the fragment manager.  Just add a fragment, then add another to the same container.   Same problem.   But there's a solution for that problem.  Namely do:

```kotlin
fragment.view?.importantForAccessibility = View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO_HIDE_DESCENDANTS
```

on the fragment that's being hidden, and do:

```kotlin
fragment.view?.importantForAccessibility = View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_YES
```

on it when its on top again.

I thought it should be easy enough to apply this technique to AbstractListDetailFragment, but I haven't been successful in doing so.  I thought PanelSlideListener and checking to see that `isSlideable` would do it:

```kotlin
    override fun onListPaneViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onListPaneViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        slidingPaneLayout.setPanelSlideListener(object: SlidingPaneLayout.PanelSlideListener {
            override fun onPanelSlide(panel: View, slideOffset: Float) {
            }

            override fun onPanelOpened(panel: View) {
                if (slidingPaneLayout.isSlideable) {
                    view.importantForAccessibility = View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO_HIDE_DESCENDANTS
                }

            }

            override fun onPanelClosed(panel: View) {
            }

         })
    }
```

But that's failing to handle it.  The idea would be reenable the accessibility in onPanelClosed, but I've yet to successfully disable it.  It's getting called.  But it's not having the desired effect.  Maybe the timing of when it's done that's bad?  Maybe it's the wrong view?

Comment: SO is for _questions_, not complaints.

Comment: So I guess the question is why is this happening and how might I fix it.   It must have to do with how the fragments are being added.

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your post if you hope to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The technique above doesn't work on the top level container, but:

```
    override fun onListPaneViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onListPaneViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val viewsList = listOf(vb.list, vb.emptyView, vb.spinner, vb.label, vb.bottomNavigation)

    slidingPaneLayout.setPanelSlideListener(object: SlidingPaneLayout.PanelSlideListener {
        override fun onPanelSlide(panel: View, slideOffset: Float) {
        }

        override fun onPanelOpened(panel: View) {
            if (slidingPaneLayout.isSlideable) {
                viewsList.forEach {
                    it?.importantForAccessibility = View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO_HIDE_DESCENDANTS
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onPanelClosed(panel: View) {
            if (slidingPaneLayout.isSlideable) {
                viewsList.forEach {
                    it?.importantForAccessibility = View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_YES
                }
            }
        }

     })
}
```

does. Where viewsList contains the top level controls in the fragment (inside a ConstraintLayout).  Just doesn't work on the ConstraintLayout itself.

Comment: This is a rather ugly solution, but it works.   I'd welcome better solutions.   I'd love to see a future version of AbstractListDetailFragment provider a better way to handle the problem.